# nameid-format:emailAddress is used when using email as nameid format.what is the proper nameid format when using username as namid field

Tags: saml, saml-2.0

NameIDFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress" we are using if we need to authenticate a user based on email address.if we need to use username as name id field what should be the nameid  format.i got confused .Could any one can help what would be the correct nameid for to authenticate user with username and what would be the consequences if we use nameid-format as "unspecified" please help and i am new to saml concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use NameID format `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified` instead, but you have to make sure that the IdP uses the correct value for the subject. It has to be configured and is not selected only because you use a sepcific NameID format.